# Roundinf off for decimal value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, rounding

I am trying get rounded off to nearest of 5

example  :

```
When Range is   | Rounded off 
------------------------------
102.5 - 107.4   |  105    
107.5 - 112.4   |  110
```

How to achieve this ?

please suggest me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:`Math.Round(x/5.0)*5`